# Facebook API not returning message_tags with app token

Tags: facebook, comments, token, facebook4j

I'm trying to get users mentions (message_tags) included in comments. I execute this query from Facebook explorer :

GET/v2.10/ 1575295176130351_1877507262575806?fields=comments{message_tags}

When I'm authentified as an application with an app token :
Facebook API returns only message_tags from type 'page'. API doesn't returns message_tags from type 'user'.

When I'm authentified as an user, with a user access token:
it returns all message_tags.

Someone could explain me the reason why ? I was able to get message_tags from type 'user' with an app token 2 weeks ago... I suspect API has been updated but I can't find any clear explanation in changelog.

Comment: Can’t find anything about that either; suggest you file a bug report and ask them whether this was a deliberate change, or a mistake. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Do you have an update for this?

Comment: Facebook support team confirmed the bug. It's not a priority to be resolved, so they told me to authentify with user token.